# how to solve the system of a.x=b with Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Hi i'm studying linear algebra, first of all sorry for screen shots if it's not a good idea but I don't know how to write a matrix in StackExchange.

So question gave me A Matrix and I have to find its inverse so I got the inverse :

[A Matrix and its inverse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeJAq.png)

And Now I have to solve this "A.X = B"  :

[A.X=B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1cxp.png)

I'm not sure how I should solve this, should I Multiply Matrix A inverse with 4-vector column Matrix B ? to find Matrix X ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

What happens when you multiply the equation $AX=B$ by $A^{-1}$ from the left?

Comment: well A-inverse times A well give Identity matrix ? then ?

Comment: @HusseinRedaAlBehary I said *multiply the **EQUATION***

Comment: A*A-inverse*X  = B*A-inverse ?

Comment: @HusseinRedaAlBehary ***FROM THE LEFT!*** Please read everything I write.

Comment: I started from the left !

Comment: @HusseinRedaAlBehary How do you get $AA^{-1}$ if you multiply $A$ from the left by $A^{1}$?

Comment: I get Identity-Matrix times X = A-inverse times B

Comment: @HusseinRedaAlBehary And what is $I\cdot X$ equal to?

Comment: so its going to be X = A-inverse times B ?

Comment: @HusseinRedaAlBehary There you go.

Comment: Thanks :), but you could have shorten the way by just answering YES to my suggestion in my Question at the end, But thanks for making me this about the right answer by my self :)

Comment: @HusseinRedaAlBehary True, but your sentence was so confusingly written I did not know if you are correct or not. For example, $B$ is simply a *vector*, it's not a 4-vector column matrix. Also, the point is you need to multiply the equation from the left.